# Titanium appcelerator is capricious,

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I face a big problem with titanium appcelerator, this morning i work as usual on my app dev, sundenly i am not able to run my project as this picture shows :

[image]

When i click on run i just have "Package" and iOs and android simulator are gone.

I tried rebooting the studio, my mac but nothing.

I use : Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.6.0.201605201934 and xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: close all projects...then open your project...clean it up..if not work, then again close this project and open it again...It happens when we switch between devices or simulators or Android/iOS platforms.

Try to clean the project until it show what you want. I had been through this many times, so only solution is to close all projects, open the necessary project and then try cleaning multiple times.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your interest, i clean, re-clean, re-start many time but nothing. I just solved it by re-updating the path to the sdk on setting->sdk (just click on update button on the right), i had also a merge conflict on my tiapp.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To steps you can try:**

1. Did you try to run your project via CLI ?
2. Try to locate your sdk in Studio go to settings->platforms->set titanium sdk home (if it is already set, set it again)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, where is the setting menu please?

Comment: Hello everyone, i just solved it by re-updating sdk path as @Michael Bahl suggested, i found also an merge conflict on my tiapp.xml.